# How to calculate a significant value of a definite curve/shaded region in a graph?

Tags: signal-analysis, sampling, signal-detection

The attached graph below consists of $4.5$ seconds of pattern which I have recorded via a hardware device.

[image]

The $x$-axis is the timestamp value in seconds and the $y$-axis is the hardware value. The values are taken on $0.01$ seconds of interval.

As seen in the graph, there is a definite pattern/curve from $0.5$ to $3$ seconds. I tried calculating a definite value using the below steps:

- Taking 2.5 seconds block starting from $0$ Blocks: $0 - 2.5$, $0.01 - 2.51$, $0.02 - 2.52$, etc.
- Now divide this $2.5$ second block into $5$ parts of $0.5$ seconds interval blocks. $(2.5/5 = 0.5)$
- So, first block of $0 - 2.5$ will give: $0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5$
- Now I have calculated the slope of these values $(x_2-x_1/y_2-y_1)$. This will give me $5$ slope values.
- Lastly I have added these values, $(\textrm{Slope}_1 + \textrm{Slope}_2+\ldots + \textrm{Slope}_5)/5$ to get a single average value.

The thing is this value is definite for the time block of $0.5 - 3$ seconds (the curve which I want to identify), but sometimes it comes for other time blocks also.

Also, second issue is, In the current graph, most of the values start from near $0$ or at $0$ on the $y$-axis. In real time, values can start from $-1$ or $1$ also, but the curve will still be the same, I have tested it.

I think the only way is to calculate the value of the curve, as the $y$ values are not definite, but the curve shape is. In real time I would have around $30$ seconds of data and I need to check if any $2.5$ seconds from those $30$ seconds contains a curve like this.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate problem description. What do you mean by "definite value" and "definite curve"? Do you mean that you look for this particular pattern of the curve in a larger signal portion? Do you need to identify, where and how often it occurs? Can you provide us the test data you plotted there online?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, " particular pattern of the curve in a larger signal portion" is what I am looking for. I require the same. Let me see If I can provide the test data. But for starters, it can be any data based on 0.01 interval seconds. Actually, I have 4 type curves which I need to identify. I was looking for a formula to somehow calculate the area/value of a pattern for a specified time block.

Comment: From my understanding you are looking for some kind of pattern matching  algorithm which will match the shape(and not the values) of a particular pattern in a time sequence. As you mentioned that y axis values might not be the same in new time sequence, is entire curve shifted across y axis or it is scaled(linear or non-linear) ?? because if its just shifted on y axis slope based methods  will work, but if its scaled slope based methods might not be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cross-correlation to detect a known signal in a received/measured signal. Here is an example using python and numpy/scipy:

```
pattern = lambda t: 0.8*(abs(t-1) < 1).astype(int) * np.sin(-2*np.pi*t/2)
Fs = 100.0
t = np.arange(-1, 15, 1/Fs)
t_samp = np.arange(-0.5, 2, 1/Fs)

sigma = 0.02  # add some noise to the measurement

rx = -1+0.1*(t-3)+pattern(t) + pattern(t-4)+pattern(t-9) + np.sqrt(sigma) * np.random.randn(len(t))
patsamples = pattern(t_samp)

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(t, rx)
plt.ylim((-4,4))
plt.title('The received signal')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(t_samp, patsamples)
plt.title('The pattern you look for')

plt.subplot(212)
metric = np.correlate(rx, patsamples, 'same')
plt.plot(t, metric)
plt.title('The correlation metric')
plt.grid(True)

peaks = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(-metric, np.array([2.5])/Fs, min_snr=0.5)
peaks = np.array(peaks)
peaks = peaks[metric[peaks]>40]
plt.stem(t[peaks], metric[peaks])
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

As you see, this works also when there is an offset or a constant slope in the received signal. In the correlation metric you see peaks, which you need to detect. There is the scipy.signal function find_peaks_cwt, however it is not very intuitively usable. For better/easier implementation of find_peaks you can have a look at [this page](https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/).